Asynchronous invalidation when using useMutation (react-query) in conjunction with Rails' ActiveJob?
Note: Question's essence is the relation between react-query and Rails' ActiveJob.
I have a situation in my application where the frontend sends a request to update a resource, which triggers an asynchronous background task. When this task completes, it updates the resource in the database, and the UI needs to react to that change.
Here's an example: A user clicks a button to change the text shown in a lesson's video. The server responds with 200 and starts an asynchronous video generation task for the lesson. When finished, it sends a notification to the UI. However, useMutation won't invalidate the queries related to that mutation when video generation finishes, since it has already done so right after receiving the 200 response from the initial mutation request.
I've implemented a system for async invalidation where my custom hook watches for notification changes and triggers the related invalidations when a change occurs. I'll share some pseudo code below that explains my approach.
My question is: Am I overengineering this mechanism? Is there a simpler way to achieve this functionality? While my current system works, it feels overly complex and has edge cases. I'm curious if others have faced similar issues and how they've solved them.

This is how I run my custom mutation hook
const { mutate } = useCustomMutation('/resource', { invalidations: ['/resource'] })

This is how it handles the async invalidation decisions:
const useCustomMutation = (url, options) => {
  const mutationFn = () => {
    // logic that inspects response from server to determine whether mutation has started a background task
    // if so, saves it in UI state with invalidations that needs to happen
    // something like:
    if (resp.hasStartedBackgroundTasks()) {
       saveAppState({ 
         asyncTaskId: resp.backgroundTaskId, 
         runAsyncInvalidation: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: invalidations }) 
      })
    }
  }

  return useMutation({ mutationFn })
}

Then, where I receive notifications, I run the async invalidations set in the app state:
useEffect(() => {
  if (notifications.includes(appState.asynTasksId}) {
    appState.runAsyncInvalidation()
  }
}, [notifications])


I think your on the right track, you could read through https://tkdodo.eu/blog/using-web-sockets-with-react-query and see if you could improve it. Probably I would just set up the central useEffect subscription to invalidate the queries we need instead of faffing about with the functions in appState.

Hey thanks for the insights. My implementation of how I subscribe to the websocket matches with that article. Pretty straight forward.
I ended up moving the state I set to track pending async invalidations to local storage because I realized a refresh wipes app state and then I lose the invalidation... And, you might be right about moving that logic to centra useEffect.

Cool, let me know if it works out.
